# in nested eager loading sequelize query, fetch only some attributes

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, eager-loading

Here's my query for fetching shows from a database, plus its associated venue and bands.
I really only want to get the names of the bands and venue. (`name` is the field in both of those tables.) The code below is fetching the whole record, though, and not just the field that I want.

```
const getAllShows = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const shows = await Show.findAll({
            include: [
                { model: User, as: 'bands', through: { attributes: ['name'] } }, 
                { model: Venue, through: { attributes: ['name'] }}
            ],
        });
        res.status(200).send(shows); 
    }
    catch(err) {
        res.send(400);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `attributes` is misplaced - it doesn't belong under the `through` (btw, depending on your associations, you may not even need `through`).

Try changing like this:

`{ model: User, as: 'bands', attributes: ['name']},`

You might also consider field aliases, like this:

`{ model: User, as: 'bands', attributes: [['name', 'band_name']]},`

hth